# Android - Layout rendered wrong on similar devices

Tags: android, layout, resources

I have two emulated Genymotion devices:

- **(A)** Google Nexus One (API 10 - 2.3.7) 480x800, 240dpi.
- **(B)** Google Nexus S   (API 16 - 4.1.1) 480x800, 240dpi.

I have a xml layout file of a dialog located in layout-land resource folder.

On the device **(A)** the layout is displayed accordingly as my expectations. On the device **(B)** it **is not** displayed correctly. The width of the layout is squished so the different views that comprise it overlap.

Shouldn't be the layout displayed exactly the same in both devices since both have the same dimensions?

**EDIT 1:**

As requested here is an XML layout that causes the problem (See image below):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:ctx=".SomeActivity"
        android:id="@+id/parent_some_activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:background="#ffe9edde"
            >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="#ff851514"
            android:text="Some text here"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textColor="#ff851514"
            android:text="Some more text"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/label_4"/>

    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_option_1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_option_2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textColor="#ff851514"
            android:text="Another label"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radio_group_1"/>

        <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" BLA "
                android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/label_3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textColor="#ff851514"
            android:text="More Text"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_5"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label_4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_4">

        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_option_3"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_option_4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff851514"
            android:text="One more label"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/label_1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkbox_2"/>

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check 3"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkbox_2"/>

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check 2"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox_3"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label_5"/>

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check 1"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkbox_2"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Check 4"
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_4"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_3"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkbox_3"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner_2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner_2"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT 2:**

The only solution I have so far is to define a dimension specifically for the devices where the problem occurs. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: Are both emulators set up the same?

Comment: As stated in the question those are the emulators configurations. I am not sure what else you might need or mean with your question. Also, they are automatically set up by Genymotion.

Comment: Just because they have the same dimensions and dpi doesn't mean they aren't scaled differently on the screen

Comment: Possibly a difference in view/layout management between API 10 and API 16? Doubt it but a possibility? Have you tried matching API's just to check?

Comment: "Shouldn't be the layout displayed exactly the same in both devices since both have the same dimensions ?" -- possibly, but since you elected not to provide the layout XML files and screenshots showing your effects, it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @zgc7009 What do you mean with trying to match API's?

Comment: You have one API set to 10 and another set to 16, why not set the device API's to the same API? But I am with @CommonsWare hard to tell without a provided layout.

Comment: @CommonsWare There's only one XML file of interest that is being rendered differently. Also, I know I didn't provide examples but I don't know how to provide them with out disclosing information that I consider private. Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this? Maybe just provide the most important parts (don't know which they may be).

Comment: @zgc7009 Unfortunately I think I cannot change that setting on the emulators provided by Genymotion since they are based(?) on a predefined VM.

Comment: "Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this?" -- not really, in part because I have no idea what you consider to be private about a layout resource. You may just need to debug it yourself, using Hierarchy View and/or **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see why your layout rules are behaving as they are.